# It will transfer the data in Excel to the SQL database, but will not add the same ones

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I'm trying to import data from excel into the sql database, but if the data is the same, the data will not add the same ones, it will add the newly added ones, but I couldn't figure it out. I would appreciate it if you could help me how to do it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;



namespace bu_sefer_kesin_olacak
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog a = new OpenFileDialog();
            a.Filter = "Excel Dosyası |*.xlsx| Excel Dosyası |*.xls";
            a.Title = "Ürün Dosyasını Seçiniz";
            if (a.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                OleDbConnection baglan;
                baglan = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + a.FileName + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=False;'");
                baglan.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet_0$]", baglan);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adap.Fill(dt);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                baglan.Close();


            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string BaglantiAdresi = "Server=.;Database=test;User Id=stajyer_sql;Password=123456;";
            SqlConnection baglan2 = new SqlConnection(BaglantiAdresi);
            
            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Insert into bu_sefer_kesin_olacak3(Onay_durumu,Kategori,Kapatildigi_zaman,Olusturuldugu_zaman,Departman,Aciklama,Bildirim_no,Sure_sonu,Ilk_Cevap_Verildigi_Zaman_Saat,Ilk_Yanit_Durumu,Initial_Response_Time,Grup,Harici_sistem_ticket_no,Etki,Oyuncu_etkilesimi,Oge,Temsilci_etkilisimleri,Oncelik,Talep_sahibi_eposta_adresi,Talep_sahibi_adi,Cozumleme_durumu,Cozuldugu_zaman_saat,Cozuldugu_zaman,Temsilci,Kaynak,Durum,Alt_kategori,Konu,Anket_sonuclari,Etiketler,Tur,Zaman_kaydedildi,Tip,En_son_guncellendigi_zaman,Aciliyet,Cozum_ureten)Values(@Onay_durumu,@Kategori,@Kapatildigi_zaman,@Olusturuldugu_zaman,@Departman,@Aciklama,@Bildirim_no,@Sure_sonu,@Ilk_Cevap_Verildigi_Zaman_Saat,@Ilk_Yanit_Durumu,@Initial_Response_Time,@Grup,@Harici_sistem_ticket_no,@Etki,@Oyuncu_etkilesimi,@Oge,@Temsilci_etkilisimleri,@Oncelik,@Talep_sahibi_eposta_adresi,@Talep_sahibi_adi,@Cozumleme_durumu,@Cozuldugu_zaman_saat,@Cozuldugu_zaman,@Temsilci,@Kaynak,@Durum,@Alt_kategori,@Konu,@Anket_sonuclari,@Etiketler,@Tur,@Zaman_kaydedildi,@Tip,@En_son_guncellendigi_zaman,@Aciliyet,@Cozum_ureten)", baglan2);

                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Onay_durumu", row.Cells["Onay_durumu"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Kategori", row.Cells["Kategori"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Kapatildigi_zaman", row.Cells["Kapatildigi_zaman"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Olusturuldugu_zaman", row.Cells["Olusturuldugu_zaman"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Departman", row.Cells["Departman"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Aciklama", row.Cells["Aciklama"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Bildirim_no", row.Cells["Bildirim_no"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sure_sonu", row.Cells["Sure_sonu"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Ilk_Cevap_Verildigi_Zaman_Saat", row.Cells["Ilk_Cevap_Verildigi_Zaman_Saat"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Ilk_Yanit_Durumu", row.Cells["Ilk_Yanit_Durumu"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Initial_Response_Time", row.Cells["Initial_Response_Time"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Grup", row.Cells["Grup"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Harici_sistem_ticket_no", row.Cells["Harici_sistem_ticket_no"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Etki", row.Cells["Etki"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Oyuncu_etkilesimi", row.Cells["Oyuncu_etkilesimi"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Oge", row.Cells["Oge"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Temsilci_etkilisimleri", row.Cells["Temsilci_etkilisimleri"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Oncelik", row.Cells["Oncelik"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Talep_sahibi_eposta_adresi", row.Cells["Talep_sahibi_eposta_adresi"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Talep_sahibi_adi", row.Cells["Talep_sahibi_adi"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Cozumleme_durumu", row.Cells["Cozumleme_durumu"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Cozuldugu_zaman_saat", row.Cells["Cozuldugu_zaman_saat"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Cozuldugu_zaman", row.Cells["Cozuldugu_zaman"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Temsilci", row.Cells["Temsilci"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Kaynak", row.Cells["Kaynak"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Durum", row.Cells["Durum"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Alt_kategori", row.Cells["Alt_kategori"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Konu", row.Cells["Konu"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Anket_sonuclari", row.Cells["Anket_sonuclari"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Etiketler", row.Cells["Etiketler"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Tur", row.Cells["Tur"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Zaman_kaydedildi", row.Cells["Zaman_kaydedildi"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Tip", row.Cells["Tip"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("En_son_guncellendigi_zaman", row.Cells["En_son_guncellendigi_zaman"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Aciliyet", row.Cells["Aciliyet"].Value.ToString());
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Cozum_ureten", row.Cells["Cozum_ureten"].Value.ToString());

                baglan2.Open();
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                baglan2.Close();

            }
            MessageBox.Show("Aktarıldı");
        }                                                                    
    }                                                                        
}
```

Comment: Simply try to select the primary value from the db. If it succeeds the record is already there..

Comment: Thank you for the answer @TaW. What will happen when you add new data to Excel. simply can you share the code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; I don't have any code..

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you want to say @TaW